# Issue with if statement in Unix

Tags: grep, ksh

I am getting the output of the first `if` script but unable to get the output of the second part of the `if` statement in the below script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

err_abc=`grep -r "XYZ" /home |wc -l`
err_AB=`grep -r "XYZ" /home` > /dev/null 2>&1
err_ERR=`grep -r "ERROR" /home |wc -l`
err_eRR=`grep -r "ERROR" /home` > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $err_abc -gt 0 ]
then
    echo "$err_AB"
else
    echo "No errors found"

    if [ $err_ERR -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "$err_eRR"
    else
        echo " \n No err files found"
        exit 0
    fi
fi
```

Comment: why nested `if`s ?

Comment: you mean `grep -r -c "XYZ" /home` ?

Comment: @User123 I think he means why are both of your `fi` statements at the end.  One of them should be before your second `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the code is doing what you think it's doing?  Let's indent it so that we can more easily see the logic:

```
if [ $err_abc -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$err_AB"
else
    echo "No errors found"
    if [ $err_ERR -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "$err_eRR"
    else
        echo " \n No err files found"
        exit 0
    fi
fi
```

Your second `if` block is only executing if and only if the first block's test is falsy.  If you want both tests to be run in all cases, this needs to be rewritten:

```
if [ $err_abc -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$err_AB"
else
    echo "No errors found"
fi
if [ $err_ERR -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$err_eRR"
else
    echo " \n No err files found"
    exit 0
fi
```

Also, the `exit 0` you have in your final `if` statement's `else` clause is only executed if any only if the second test is falsy.  If this is not your intent, that statement should be moved appropriately.

Comment: No, I want to check the both conditions ...first as well the second one...second if statement is not dependent on first one.

Comment: It is as written. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of extra work to set the variables: you're recursively grepping 4 separate times. You only need to do that once:

```
all_errs=$(grep -r -E "XYZ|ERROR" /home 2>/dev/null)
```

Then the other information can be retrieved from that variable

```
err_AB=$(grep "XYZ" <<< "$all_errs)
err_abc=$(wc -l <<< "$err_AB")

err_eRR=$(grep "ERROR" <<< "$all_errs")
err_ERR=$(wc -l <<<"$err_eRR")
```